# Can't intall chef-manage rpm package

Tags: centos, chef-infra

I have CentOS and chef-server. I try to install chef-manage, but something wrong. 
When I start install my rpm package 
[I have this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT4zE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Chef Server (i.e. chef-server-core) first. Then install Manage afterwards via the addons system.